# How to run web-socket with system starts in Ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: laravel, sockets, websocket

I have the Laravel project which uses the web-socket. In this time the Laravel is running on port `8000`. And the web socket is running on port `8090` successfully. Currently, I use this command in the Laravel project folder to initiate the web-socket
`php artisan websocket:init`

But if I closed the terminal, the running also socket will be terminate.

How can I run the web socket along with system starts or automatically?

Comment: This question might be better asked on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Supervisor

This little application is built for exactly what you are asking. it allows you to run  non-daemonising applications without being signed in to the server and keeping a terminal session open.

[Install and Configure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

[Supervisor Docs](http://supervisord.org/installing.html)

I use this to serve my nodejs websocket server and it runs exactly as expected with listener for auto restart if the application for any reason stops unexpectedly.

Comment: Will auto restart if the system restarts ?

Comment: Thank you @Petay87, As the DigitalOcean link and the following link I created a bash script file to run^^^

Comment: Can it be used to restart the WebSockets when they fail?